# how to clear an numpy array by it's elements length

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2 dimensional numpy array:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3], 
            [4,5,6,7], 
            [2,3,4]])
```

How can i efficiently remove the element(row), which contains more than 3 elements(columns), without knowledge about its position?

```
    a=np.array([[1,2,3], 
                [2,3,4]])
```

"Remove all rows which are longer than 3."

Comment: You don't have a 2D numpy array; they can't vary row lengths like that.  You probably have a 1D numpy array with `dtype=object`.

Comment: thx, but it seems to work ok, so the index to adress elements is kind of the same as in a 2d numpy array?

Comment: If you don't need to do any vector ops, or do any vector slicing. Try `a * 2`, for example, or `a[:,1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick (assuming the array is in variable a):

```
np.array([row for row in a if len(row)<=3])
```

I use a list comprehension on the numpy array a and only select the elements whose length is three or smaller.